# Would it make sense to say "pessimism biased tone"?

Tags: expressions

I am trying to write a thesis sentence for and English class assignment.
This is the sentence for context:

> This book should be added to the school's literature curriculum because of the pessimism biased tone the narrator uses to talk about his life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be simpler to say:

> Pessimistic tone

or if you're trying to emphasize the bias:

> a bias towards pessimism in his/her tone